# Inserting multiple column value in a single value with breaklines

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I insert multiple values of a column in a single value with newlines. for example i have three rows for a column called filename as F1,F2,F3 in three different rows. i want to keep this in single value of column as `F1/nF2/n/F3`

**example**

```
jobname       filename          
daily          F1.txt              
daily          F2.txt                  
daily          F3.txt
```

**desired output**

```
jobname       filename          

daily          F1.txt 
               F2.txt
               F2.txt
```

Comment: " i want to keep this in single value of column as F1/nF2/n/F3" - NO, you don't! Read up on normalisation.

Comment: @MitchWheat a little to general. Maybe he tries to improve performance by denormalization. I dont thinks its the case but it could be.

Comment: @Andre: yeah, that's really going to be the case.....Maybe I have a pet unicorn :)

Comment: sorry i am not much clear on normalisation, but still would like to ask can i not insert values from one table,having data like the fisrt example, to another table to get data in desired output condition.beacuse i am not updating or making changes to the same table but i am inserting values from on etable to another..please comment or reply..

Comment: did you see this bit?: "Read up on normalisation."

Comment: @Vivek i think the DH__ 's solution is right. it will work as per your given requirement.

Comment: @Shell i m not clear on " FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,2,'') filename                                                              what the above part of the code will do.. anything to do with XML path..????

Comment: that question should be asked to answer owner.

Comment: @Rahul I suggested that because the output of sql query is same as defined in OP's Question.

Comment: This is one of two things. Either a formatting issue which should be left to the front end. Or it is a serious problem with normalization. 1NF states that we do not have multiple values in a given intersection.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This query will return data as per your desired output. SO you can use this query for insertion.

```
select distinct t.[jobname],
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ' ' + t1.filename
         from tablename t1
         where t.[jobname] = t1.[jobname]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,2,'') filename
from tablename t;
```

See [sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cefeb/2).

Comment: Mind including little explanation about what your code does?

Comment: @Rahul yes. I have modified ans.